# Styling Html.textbox in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to give style to the textbox but its now working.This is what i have done so far.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signin_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class=" modal-header">
                Create An Account
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

            @using(Html.BeginForm())
            { 
                <table class="signin_tbl">    
                    <tr>
                        <td class="signin_txt"><h5>Email</h5></td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBox("Name", new { style=" height:70px; "} )  </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="signin_txt">Password</td>
                        <td class="signin_tb" >@Html.TextBox("password") </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
            </div>
```

And this is what i am getting as output:

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything yourself to solve the problem before posting here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must set textbox value to your value and followed by your html attribute like:

```
@Html.TextBox("Name",[Value Or Null], new { @style=" height:70px; "} )
```

Answer (score 7):

Change your `@Html.TextBox()` as shown below :

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", null ,new { style=" height:70px; "} )
```

The second parameter of `@Html.TextBox()` is `value` of `textbox` and not `htmlattributes`.

Answer (score 3):

Specify you want to specify the `htmlAttributes` argument of the `TextBox` method instead of it's content. You can specify the argument passed in to the method like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", htmlAttributes: new { style=" height:70px; "} )
```